# how to stop a gallery slideshow

Tags: themes, images, shortcode, gallery

I am using the Dynamix WP theme. I have three images displaying in a loop with fade effect. The images continue to fade from one to other. However I would like to stop this effect once all images have shown.
i.e on page load three images will fade from one to other and then stop.

How can I achieve this?
Is there something I can add to the shortcode to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can't,
Dynamix WP theme uses piecemaker.swf to run its slide show and by looking at the [documentation](http://www.modularweb.net/content/en/piecemaker/documentation.pdf) you can see that they don't have a none loop setting.

your best bet is to try to replace it with a different flash viewer that has a none loop option like [CU3ER image rotator](http://www.progressivered.com/cu3er/) which i know can work great with nextgen gallery plugin for easy modifications.

Hope this helps

Comment: Ok thank you. I don't think I can use a different gallery pligin because i am using the dynamix gallery throughout the site. I only want the loop to stop on the home page. I have found if i use a second gallery they all stop working! Thanks anyway.